# In a MOSFET, what does the P+ region mean in this picture?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Wikipedia has several pictures of MOSFETs and various types of them. Here is one.

[image]

Notice that the Source and Body are connected. I understand this is to ensure there is no forward-bias or reverse-bias between them.

What I don't understand is, what is that "P+" region where the body connection exists? What is it and what is it's purpose? If it's a more highly-doped p-region then I don't understand why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a semiconductor, you can't generally make a resistive (ohmic) contact to a lightly doped region (as in the p substrate or bulk here). Such a contact would likely be very resistive, or act as a Schottky diode.

So (just like the N+ in the drain), a very heavy P+ diffusion is made for the metallic contact. This creates a degenerate (i.e. metallic or conductive) junction between the metal and the semiconductor, thus giving a good electrical contact to the bulk.

A secondary advantage of this is that the P+ bulk and N+ source can be quite close together. Having a low resistance connecting shorting these makes the FET more robust during high VDS voltages.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot. But a follow-up question, is the same thing required on the opposite mosfet? So an n-substrate and p-type channels, do you need an N+ region for the ohmic contact?

Comment: Yes; you need a ++ contact for all lightly doped regions.